# ArgumentError: SMTP-AUTH requested but missing user name + ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, actionmailer, telnet, mailer

I m not able to sent mail using actionmailer everytime I try to deliver the mail using actionmailer It report me with error

ArgumentError: SMTP-AUTH requested but missing user name

This is Strange as I'm able to sent mail via Telnet but not using ActionMailer

Attaching Telnet Screenshot

Here my SMTP settings

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => '216.224.183.100',
    :port                 => 25,
    :domain               => '[domain_name]',
    :username             => "[username]",
    :password             => "[password]",
    :authentication       => 'plain',
   :enable_starttls_auto => true
 }
```

Can anyone Please tell as to via the Mail is not getting sent

[image]

Comment: Um, why did you not redact the correct username and password from the picture? Only the incorrect ones.

Comment: Your telnet session is not using STARTTLS while your code explicitly requests it. You are not testing the same thing.

Comment: @tripleee that not the case as I tried removing the enable tls key and send message again same error also tried by deleting authentication key still no luck

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Got it. It's `user_name`, and not `username`.

Comment: Goodness, just spent 30 minutes trying to figure out my problem, and this was it.